# Doctrine2 empty collection creates unnecessary query

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an Doctrine2 entity with an `images` collection.  Here is my query:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('page');
    $qb->select('page, image');
    $qb->where('page.id = ?1')
       ->leftJoin('page.images', 'image')
       ->setParameter(1, $id);

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
```

When I call `$result->getImages()` and the `images` collection is empty there is an extra call to the database.  How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem with native query and I solved it by marking the freshly mapped collection as initialized .

```
if($result->getImages() instanceof PersistentCollection)
    $result->getImages()->setInitialized(true);
}
```

Doctrine don't call anymore the DB to check if there is children. Huge optimisation !

Comment: Thanks for this.  At some point this seemed to be fixed in doctrine as well.  I no longer have this problem.

Comment: Which version of Doctrine do you use ? This hack works with v2.2.3